# Searching a word like not exactly what I give in textbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I search a word from my DB using model in codeigniter. I done the search for exact word searching. but I need also find a word when I give partial word. I use LIKE clause for search a word. But I don't know how to use LIKE% clause in my model function.

Model:

```
public function get_search() {
  $match = $this->input->post("search");
  $match1 = $this->input->post("search1");
  $match2 = $this->input->post("search2");
  $match3 = $this->input->post("search3");
  $match4 = $this->input->post("search4");
  $match5 = $this->input->post("search5");
  $match6 = $this->input->post("search6");
  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM patient_creation;");
  $this->db->where("patient_id like '$match' OR mobile like '$match1' OR name like '$match2' OR fathername like '$match3' OR address like '$match4' OR created BETWEEN '$match5' AND '$match6'");
  //$this->db->or_where("name LIKE '".$match2."%'"); 
  $query = $this->db->get("patient_creation");
  return $query->result();
}
```

I need LIKE% search for $match2, $match3 and $match4 variables.

Comment: This will only match string "$match" or "$match1" or else to your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
$this->db->where("patient_id like '$match' OR mobile like '$match1' OR name like '$match2' OR fathername like '$match3' OR address like '$match4' OR created BETWEEN '$match5' AND '$match6'");
```

to

```
$this->db->where("patient_id like '".$match."' OR mobile like '".$match1."' OR name like '".$match2."' OR fathername like '".$match3."%' OR address like '".$match4."%' OR created BETWEEN '".$match5."' AND '".$match6."'");
```

Comment: i tried.its not works correctly. because its affect another variables.  It show all unrelated words also.

Comment: So your query is wrong, right? i thought it's just about the `LIKE` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Note the semicolon in `SELECT * FROM patient_creation;` prepare query string and use in query func like,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM patient_creation where patient_id like '$match' OR mobile like '$match1' OR name like '$match2' OR fathername like '$match3' OR address like '$match4' OR created BETWEEN '$match5' AND '$match6'";

$this->db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_search() {
  $match = $this->input->post("search");
  $match1 = $this->input->post("search1");
  $match2 = $this->input->post("search2");
  $match3 = $this->input->post("search3");
  $match4 = $this->input->post("search4");
  $match5 = $this->input->post("search5");
  $match6 = $this->input->post("search6");
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->like("patient_id" ,$match);
  $this->db->or_like("name" ,$match2);
  $this->db->or_like("fathername" ,$match3);
  $this->db->or_like("address" ,$match4);
  $this->db->or_like("name" ,$match2);
  $this->db->where('created  >=', $match5);
  $this->db->where('created  <=', $match6);
  $query = $this->db->get("patient_creation");
  return $query->result();
 }
```